# Switch from UIView to UITableview on press of a button

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I made a button and connected it to an action in interface builder. What do I need to do in the action method to switch from displaying a view to displaying a table view?

Here is some of my code:

```
//  SwitchToTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SwitchToTableViewController : UIViewController {


}

-(IBAction) switch : (id) sender;

@end
```

and

```
//SwitchToTableViewController.m
#import "SwitchToTableViewController.h"
#import "Table.h"
@implementation SwitchToTableViewController

-(IBAction) switch : (id) sender{

    // what is i need to write here to switch to tableview


}

@end
```

and

```
//table.m
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Table : UITableViewController {


}

@end
```

and

```
//table.h
#import "Table.h"


@implementation Table

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: You had a huge amount of code in here that was completely irrelevant. It puts people off reading the question - there is no need to include every line of code in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

1. Create an instant of Table.
2. Pass any data over to this instant, most likely an array so that you can use it to display cells data.  You need to create some iVars in your Table class first.  Currently you don't have any.
3. Chose one of many ways to present your Table instant.

Look into Apple's  [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It has quite a bit sample code.

Edit for sample code:

In your `SwitchToTableViewController.h` file, add this line:

```
#import "Table.h"
```

In your `SwitchToTableViewController.m`, make this changes

```
-(IBAction) switch : (id) sender{

    // what is i need to write here to switch to tableview
    Table *myTable = [[Table alloc]init];
    myTable.cellArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Item1", @"Item2", @"Item3", nil];  //only an example to be displayed
    [self presentViewController:myTable animated:YES completion:nil];  // present your Table - view controller

}
```

Your `Table.h` file should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Table : UITableViewController {

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cellArray;  // adding this line to get data from the parent
@end
```

In your `Table.m`, make this changes

```
@implementation Table

@synthesize cellArray;  //add this line right after @implementation Table

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return cellArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two view *controllers* here, not two views. It's very important to realise the difference between those two concepts. I've put in bold in the answer below some other key words you need to read up on.

To show another view controller in response to something like a button press, you need to create a new instance of your destination view controller, then get it on the screen somehow.

There are many ways to do this but the simplest way, for a beginner, would be to do all this in **storyboards**. Add both of your view controllers to the storyboard.

Your initial view controller (with the button) should be embedded in a **UINavigationController**. **Control-drag** from the button to your table view controller. This will create a **segue**. Choose "push" from the list of options.

Hey presto, your table view will now appear on screen when you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a SingleView Application (UIViewController based) name it as SwitchingView.

Then add a UITableView above the view. Connect using Interface builder. Set delegate and datasource of tableview as the SwitchingView.

Also add a button on the view (before adding table view). Set table view is Hidden using IB(interface builder).

In button Action do

```
      tableview.hidden = NO;
```

This will show your Table view!!! If you want to show view again, just make

```
      tableview.hidden = YES;
```

in tableView:didSelectForIndexPathRow method.